# Backbone JS Routing not working as I expect

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browser-history

I think I'm missing some basics about Backbone's routing functions.

I'm building an app and it looks something like so:

`file: app.js`

```
App = {}
App.nav = new Backbone.Router;
require('app/controller');
```

`file: controller.js`

```
App.nav.route('home', 'home', function () {
    console.log("Home Activated");
});

App.navigate('home');
```

At this point the browser changes the URL in the address bar to `/home` but nothing happens and I don't get the `Home Activated` console message.

I've tried using my own routing class (i.e. `Backbone.Router.extend({})`) but I don't really see a point in it as I still need to initialize it, and I want to use a central history/navigation in my app that all modules/controllers add routing to it rather than creating a router for every controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15):

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-navigate

From the documentation:

> If you wish to also call the route function, set the trigger option to true.

But as OlliM wrote, you need to activate the history first!

So your answer should be:

```
Backbone.history.start();
App.nav.navigate('home', {trigger: true});
```

edit:
forgot to put "nav"

Comment: `{trigger: true}` isn't part of the solution here. Backbone will default to trigger:true if no options are specified. Here's the code snippet: 
`navigate: function(fragment, options) {
   if (!History.started) return false;
   if (!options || options === true) options = {trigger: !!options};`

Comment: Your link has 404'd.

Answer (score 6):

For the routing to work, you need to call `Backbone.history.start()` after setting up your routes (basically after you've done everything else). See: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History-start

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point this out as it saved me a world of hurt and heartache.

If you are routing to a custom page such as

```
Backbone.router.navigate('/some/page'); // does not work
```

And it appears to not be working. Add a trailing '/'

```
Backbone.router.navigate('/some/page/'); // works
```

This cost me a few hours of troubleshooting...